# is it possible to use the past continuous with before?

Tags: past-continuous

Is it possible to use the past continuous with before? For example: We were watching television before you arrived last night.
Or is simple past the only option?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're getting at here. Compare *I **was watching** my favourite program before you turned the TV off* and *I **watched** my favourite program before you turned the TV off*. In the first case you probably *didn't* get to see the end of the program before it was turned off, but in the second case you probably *did* see the whole thing. It really just depends on what you intend to say - there are no rules banning certain combinations that I can think of here.

Comment: ...note that in your specific example context, arguably there are slight nuances of difference between ***before*** and reasonable alternatives such as ***when*** or ***until***.

Comment: I just want to express what I was doing before the person arrived. I thought that maybe the past continuous can't be used with before.

Comment: Well, compare *I was making your supper before you arrived,* and *I made your supper before you arrived.* The first is probably explaining why supper *isn't* on the table (speaker hadn't finished making it), whereas the second is probably explaining why supper ***is*** on the table (because speaker made it earlier, perhaps as a gesture of goodwill).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly. As with many choices of aspect in English, either is possible, and differs only in how the speaker wishes to refer to the events. The choice of *watched* implies that, for the purpose of the current discourse, the speaker is regarding the watching as a completed act. *Were watching* suggests that the speaker has the watching in mind as a continuing process - perhaps they are then going on to talk about something that happened while we were watching.

Comment: is it true that the use "was watching" here  would require me as a speaker to talk about events that happened during "watching" and thus force me to add some events in simple past "Before you arrived I was watching my fav. TV show and saw one really interesting commercial". Is it obligatory to add the events?

Comment: No9, it doesn't force anything of the kind. It may set up an expectation that you are going to do so, but that's not the only way it's used. A counter example is something like "You know you've alwys told me that X? Well, I was watching a documentary last night, and it seems you're wrong". The function of the continuous here is mainly a softening device - it makes the statement seem more tentative, and softens the effect of disagreeing with the other person.